# query only if, if clause returns false mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to figure out a way to query my schema at [sqlfillde](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22283) with a if clause,  basically i need to check if the table has rows matching if label == ? OR if name == ?, so the following query gets the job done. in case if sqlfiddle lag, i'll put the scheme below

```
id name      label description
1  Grams      G     Used to measure light weight items
1  Kilograms  G     Used to measure heavy weight items
3  M Liters   ML    Used to measure liquids
4  Grams G    L     Used to measure liquids

SELECT * FROM `catutype` WHERE label = "G" OR name = "Grams"
```

But if the matched record's id == 2, i wan't to exclude that record. so i tried this,

```
SELECT * FROM `catutype` WHERE id!= 2 AND label = "G" OR name = "Grams"
```

As you can see, it didn't work out. the only solution i got was through a sub query

```
SELECT *,(SELECT label FROM catutype WHERE name = "Grams") as "type" FROM catutype WHERE catutype.id != 2
```

But still i'm unable to run two sub quires to check if label has matches, to make it more clear, i'll write a simple Pseudocode which i need in mysql.

```
if(id!=2)
{
check if label = ? OR name = ?
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM `cat_type` WHERE id!= 2 AND (label = "KG" OR name = "Kilo-Grams")
```

This is because of operator precedence, so you will have to make use of `()`, to exclude the conditions.

Explanation: Using `()`, it will check that `id!=2` **AND** the rest of the part will be treated as a single expression i.e. it will check that `label = "KG" OR name = "Kilo-Grams"` as well. So the query will give correct result if both the parts are satisfied.

Comment: Welcome @droiddude :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about operator precedence,you need parentheses since AND has higher precedence than OR

```
SELECT * FROM `catutype` WHERE id!= 2 AND (label = "G" OR name = "Grams")
```

Without them your statement is parsed as

```
SELECT * FROM `catutype` WHERE (id!= 2 AND label = "G") OR name = "Grams"
```